# Orbeon DataBase conectivity

Tags: orbeon

Could you please help to connect Orbeon Form Builder to MySql.

Please find the below useful details:

OS: Window 8, Server: Liferay Tomcat, Database: MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the step in the [documentation](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/persistence/relational-db.html), specifically the steps for MySQL. If anything is unclear, post specific questions on StackOverflow or in the [forum](http://discuss.orbeon.com/).